# Finding index of change between two strings

Tags: swift

Given:

```
let string a = "hello world"
```

and

```
let string b = "hello! world"
```

or

```
let string b = "hell world"
```

what the best way to find the index of change? (5 or 4)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `commonPrefix` like so:

```
let a = "hello world"
let b = "hello! world"
let index = a.commonPrefix(with: b).characters.count
print(index)    // prints 5
```

Note that the order of `a` and `b` doesn't matter.

---

Here's an updated function that returns `nil` if there is nothing in common, otherwise it returns the index of the change (previous solution was buggy).

```
func indexOfChangeBetween(a: String, and b: String) -> Int? {
    var index = a.commonPrefix(with: b).characters.count
    if index < 1 {
        return nil
    }
    return index - 1
}
```

Test:

```
print(indexOfChangeBetween(a: "", and: ""))     // nil
print(indexOfChangeBetween(a: "x", and: ""))    // nil
print(indexOfChangeBetween(a: "", and: "x"))    // nil
print(indexOfChangeBetween(a: "x", and: "x"))   // 0
print(indexOfChangeBetween(a: "ab", and: "a"))  // 0
print(indexOfChangeBetween(a: "a", and: "ab"))  // 0
print(indexOfChangeBetween(a: "ab", and: "ab")) // 1
```

Comment: Your last solution is asymmetric: It returns 1 for "ab"/"a", but nil for "a"/"ab".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the hashmap to mapping the strings to a map
For example

Key : Hello world
Value : Hello world 
If key!= value then we know the order has hanged .